# Bringing libcurl into a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I'm trying to pull [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) into a large C++ project.

However I am having trouble getting it to compile.  I see errors coming from ws2def.h, winsock2.h, and ws2tcpip.h

Some of the errors look like this:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'iSockaddrLength'  ws2def.h  225
error C3646: 'LPSOCKADDR' : unknown override specifier    ws2def.h  225

..

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'dwNumberOfProtocols'    winsock2.h  1259
```

I tried compiling the file that #include "curl.h" in straight C mode, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Are there any warnings about missing header files?  On my platform, curl.h is in /usr/include/curl/ so I would have to #include <curl/curl.h>.   

On Unix platforms there is a utility called curl-config which can tell which libraries and options to compile and link libcurl with.  I'm guessing you're using Windows so that may not be much help to you.

Comment: Those seem VC++ errors, if you're building it in Visual Studio take a look at the 2 guides you may find there, last time I needed to build it with that compiler I remember it was very straight forward: curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `windows.h` BEFORE you include `winsock2.h` or any libcurl headers.  Don't ask my why this sometimes works, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

Which C++ compiler are you using?  Mine does not have ws2def.h at all.  Also, keep in mind that winsock.h and winsock2.h are not compatible with each other, and some of the Win32 header files will include winsock.h by default, before your code has a chance to include winsock2.h.  So you may have to disable winsock.h by defining `_WINSOCKAPI_` in your project's compiler conditionals.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to include winsock2.h before windows.h (which includes winsock.h), instead of defining _WINSOCKAPI_.

Comment: That not always a possibility, though, depending on which compiler/framework you are using, whether precompiled headers are being used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda looks like something else is bringing in winsock defines that are conflicting with curl. Can you try to set up a project that **just** uses curl? Oh, an I had to add CURL_STATICLIB to my preprocessor definitions to make it link.